# Switch focus to another app automatically after closing last Finder window

Tags: finder, window-manager, application-switcher

Is there a way to automatically switch the focus to another app after closing the last Finder window? The default behavior is to stay focused on Finder, yet it has no windows open. I tend to ⌘W the last Finder window, then start typing assuming I'll jump straight into the app visible beneath the Finder window, only to find out I still have to ⌘-tab to it.

Also, it would be great if such a solution generalized to all applications that stay open after their last window is closed!